# plant dormancy in different locations

Tags: botany

Say plant x has a dormancy period of y in location z, for instance in Sweden. We bring this plant to another location z', say France. Are there any results with respect to if/how the dormancy period would change? (I would assume such observations would be of interest to understand how plants adapt to/can cope with climate change.)

Comment: Not really clear what you want.  Do you mean dormancy of seeds, of bulbs &c, of the kinds of perennials that die back to the ground, or trees & shrubs that lose their leaves but keep the aboveground parts?  It's also a quite complex question.  There's more going on than just winter dormancy, e.g. plants of mediterranean-type climates that go dormant in the hot, dry summer.

Comment: My question was more in the direction took by the answer of @Jonathan Moore; that is, i was missing the notion of "vernalisation". With this, i found an article https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4532801/ which answers even more my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might depend on the signal that the seed uses to end dormancy. Some seeds require 'vernalisation', that is a prolonged period of low temperatures, for them to germinate successfully.  If they don't have the cold period, they don't germinate because they 'think' that they haven't had winter yet.

Dormancy can also depend on the conditions that the parent plant lived under, so it is quite possible that if two plants were grown in different environments, their seeds would have differences in dormancy. This study looked at that effect in the 'model plant' Arabidopsis thaliana:
Donohue K., Dorn L., Griffith C., Kim E., Aguilera A., Polisetty C. R., Schmitt J. Environmental and genetic influences on the germination of Arabidopsis thaliana in the field. Evolution. 2005;596(1):740–757.

This paper gives a good review of Seed Dormancy and Germination in Arabidopsis from a few years ago:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3243337/#i1543-8120-70-1-1-b60